# Django-orm Queryset for Find object by count a particular field

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say I have two models:

```
class Testmodel1():
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Testmodel2)
    entry_time = models.DateTimeField()
    stage = choicesfiled

class Testmodel2():
    name = models.CharField()
    mobile_no = models.CharField()
```

I want to find out the object of `Testmodel1` for `contact > 3` which is created in the last 24 hours `last = arrow.utcnow().shift(hours=-24).date()`.

I am applying a query:

```
n1=Testmodel1.objects.filter(entry_time__gte=last, stage=1).annotate(t_count=Count('contact')).filter(t_count__gt=3)
```

But it seems it's not working. Because I am getting an empty queryset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: contact is a foreign key, so every TestModel1 will have exactly 1 contact. If you want there to be more than one, you have to put the foreign key on TestModel2 pointing at TestModel1. As is, every single object should have `t_count == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer. Sorry! Your code looks fine to me, so I'm just trying to find a solution by approaching it from a different direction.

Here's how I structure (sort of) similar code on one of my projects.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

....
base_date = date.today()
start_date = base_date + timedelta(days=30)
end_date = base_date
possible_holidays = Holiday.objects.filter(
    start_date__lte=start_date, end_date__gte=end_date)
```

From there, could you just do something like:

```
if possible_holidays.contact_set.count() > 3:
    pass
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Many-to-One relationship is inverted. This relationship is  a parent-child relationship, where a parent can have multiple children, but a children can only have one parent. In database this relationship is stored as a child's ForeignKey field that points to the child's parent.

In your case `Testmodel1` is a parent and `Testmodel2` is a child (`Testmodel1` can have multiple contacts represented by `Testmodel2`) This means that ForeignKey field should belong to `Testmodel2`, not `Testmodel1`.

```
class Testmodel1():
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    entry_time = models.DateTimeField()
    stage = choicesfiled

class Testmodel2():
    name = models.CharField()
    mobile_no = models.ForeignKey()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Testmodel1,
                               related_name='contacts',
                               )
```

With this model structure you can reference `Testmodel1`'s contacts as `testmodel1.contacts.all()`. Your query then should look like this:

```
n1 = (Testmodel1.objects
                .filter(entry_time__gte=last, stage=1)
                .annotate(t_count=Count('contacts'))
                .filter(t_count__gt=3)
)
```

[docs reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)